# how to mantain mouseover / hover on a concealed div

Tags: jquery, hover, hidden, zooming

I am trying to combine 2 effects on a grid of images, 1 where the image grows within a frame when the mouse hovers over it and reverts back when the mouse leaves the frame, and also for a semi-transparent div to appear over the image with links to other places.

The code I am using for the image zoom is here:

```
$(function () {
//the size of the image when hovered over, originally 200/0/0
$('#container img').hover(

function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.stop().animate({
        'opacity': '1.0',
            'height': '500px',
            'top': '-66.5px',
            'left': '-150px'
    },
    //this following number defines speed of animation enlargement ( in ms)
    20);
},

function () {
    //the size of the image when left alone
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.stop().animate({
        'opacity': '0.5',
            'height': '400px',
            'top': '-66.5px',
            'left': '-150px'
    },
    //this following number defines speed of animation back to normal ( in ms)
    700);
});
});
```

and the code for the semi-transparent mask, which is actually a hidden div containing links,  is here:

```
$('.lbwrap.1').hover(function () {
$('.over').fadeIn();
}, function () {
$('.over').fadeOut();
});
```

a working demo here (NOTE that only the third image on the top row has the div in place):
http://jsfiddle.net/9wumj4nq/

The problem Im having is that when the div appears over the image, the mouse ceases to hover, which means the image underneath shrinks back to its original size.
How do I keep the bottom image zoomed in while the covering div is in place?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is that you are binding events on `img`. Do not do that. Bind your event on the container, i.e. the `div` with the class `lbwrap` in your case.

***Relevant jQuery Code***:

```
$('.lbwrap').hover(function () {
    $(this).find('.over').fadeIn();
}, function () {
    $(this).find('.over').fadeOut();
});
```

And:

```
$('.lbwrap').hover(
    function () {
        var $img = $(this).find("img");
        $img.stop().animate({
            'opacity': '1.0',
                'height': '500px',
                'top': '-66.5px',
                'left': '-150px'
        },
...
```

***Demo Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/9wumj4nq/2/***

.

---

### Better Option:

Do not use jQuery at all for this. You can make use of CSS3 transitions. CSS transitions are more efficient than javascript based animations.

***Relevant CSS***:

```
lbwrap a img {
    transform: scale(1);    
    transition: 500ms all;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

div.lbwrap:hover img {
    transform: scale(1.5);
    opacity: 1;
}

div.lbwrap:hover .over {
    display: block;
}
```

***Demo Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/9wumj4nq/1/***

.

Comment: Thanks a lot. For some reason the CSS version is slower and uneven on my browser (Chrome, Windows 7), but good to know for future use that CSS can do animations.

Comment: @awnine: using css will also save you from a lot of convoluted js code. simplify your life and easier to understand and debug.